# PHP save sessions in many php files

Tags: php, session

I have about 4 php files and I want to save the email which will submitted on the first page and then print it on the last fourth php page..

Answer (score 1):

Add this to each PHP file to start/access the session data:
`<?php session_start(); ?>`

Then, you can set the email like this:
`<?php $_SESSION['email'] = 'test@example.com'; ?>`

You can later retreive the data at any time by referencing `$_SESSION['email']`

Comment: @FURTHERSAWAYS If an answer works for the OP, he/she should check it as the accepted answer and leave an upvote. New contributors gain reputation this way.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to start the session in every page.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

then you need to define the email in a session. ex:

```
<?php $_SESSION['email'] = "test@test.com"; ?>
```

then this seesion for email can be used in any page. ex:

```
<?php $_SESSION['email']; ?>
```

for reference:

```
 https://www.w3schools.com/pHp/php_sessions.asp

 http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php
```